# Chinese input crashes programs

Tags: macos

The problem is that when I type in Chinese, the program crashes. It happens in every program (Chrome, TextEdit, Line).

It started shortly after I added Simplified Chinese. I since removed it and also Traditional Chinese and readded, but the problem remains.

Here is the stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/raw/h0RsGM6k

Comment: Which version of OS X?  Are you talking about the Pinyin IM"s?  Have you added any non-Apple chinese fonts?

Comment: 10.11.5. No, not talking about Instant Messaging. I may have added non-Apple Chinese fonts - but just tried disabling them all, but the problem still remains.

Comment: By IM I meant input method.  Are you using pinyin?  Go to applications/fontbook and do File > Restore Standard Fonts and restart.

Answer (score 1):

Go to applications/fontbook and do File > Restore Standard Fonts and restart.